# Using while loop without process substitution, while allowing global variable value modification inside the loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that when I run from a file manager (Filza), it return an error saying

```
command substitution: syntax error near unexpected token `('.
line 56: `paste -d'\n' <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2"))'
```

But when I run it from a terminal (`./myscript.sh`), it ran with no error. Here's the code that gave the error:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="A
B
C"
var2="1
2
3"
globalvar=0

while read v1 && read v2; do
    globalvar=$(echo $v1 $v2)
done<<<$(paste -d'\n' <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2"))
```

As commented below, it's probably some shell doesn't allow process substitution, thus why it failed. This command is running on iOS environment (jailbroken). Is there alternative way to implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not all shell implementations support process substitution.

Comment: No wonder! Any idea how to implement this in another way?

Comment: You don't specify how you run the script from shell. If you run e.g. `bash script.sh`, but your shebang points to `/bin/sh`, the invocation from the file browser will use a different shell. You should also provide a complete script that you can reproduce the issue with, not just a snippet that you suspect.

Comment: How could we have an idea without knowing what kind of a shell *Filza* provides?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a [closed-source project](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.tigisoftware.filza/) and I couldn't find out what shell it's using too.

Comment: :/ Well, process substitution is an advanced feature anyway, I don't know any way of implementing it without intermediate files (and I assume you don't want that) in a portable way. So can't help, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'here document' (<<) instead of 'here string' (<<<). It is supported by most shells.

```
while read v1 && read v2; do
    globalvar=$(echo $v1 $v2)
done <<__END__
$(paste -d'\n' <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2"))
__END__
```

The other option is create a shell wrapper that will force bash (from the question, looks like bash is installed and working). Rename original script to script-run, and modify the shell script to call the script-run

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /bin/bash ${0%/*}/script-run "$@"
```

Or other equivalent.